# Is there a reference for mapping IotEdge module createOptions in deployment manifest to Docker container create options

Tags: azure-iot-edge

The title pretty much sums it up.
I'm looking for a reference to the mapping used in the following **createOptions** portion of the IoTEdge Deployment Manifest:

```
    "modules": {
        "MyCoolModule": {
            "settings": {
                "image": "mycoolimage.registry.example.com:latest",
                "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"Binds\":[\"/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix\"],\"LogConfig\":{\"Type\":\"json-file\",\"Config\":{\"max-size\": \"100m\",\"max-file\":\"2000\"}}}}"
                        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module’s createOptions is the Docker ContainerCreate structure.  We do inject some additional information as part of the module configuration, but most createOptions are passed to the container runtime as-is.

Here are some options to get the createOptions you want:

1. Use IoT Edge tooling like VS Code with IoT Edge extension and the `deployment.template.json` to have it do the escaping for you. It becomes much more readable and even includes auto-complete when using the extension.
2. Start your development by just running a container with commands like `docker run yourContainer` and once you're happy with it, inspect your container with `docker inspect yourContainer`. This will give you’re the docker run options in the Json format.
3. Look at the Docker API here:
           https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate